# Can you make a magnetic fluid that's drinkable

Tags: food-chemistry, magnetism

I need to make a ferrofluid that is drinkable so I obviously can't use the traditional method of using iron as it is harmful. Are there any chemicals that are not harmful that can take on magnetic properties or and magnetic metals that are not harmful to consume?

Comment: ‘as [iron] is harmful’ — a simplification at best. We would die without iron.

Answer (score 3):

Read [Nails for Breakfast?](http://www.flinnsci.com/Documents/demoPDFs/Chemistry/CF10628.pdf) and see if breakfast cereal manufacturers agree with your assumption "I obviously can't use the traditional method of using iron as it is harmful"

> Most people know that breakfast cereals are fortified with iron and other essential minerals and vitamins. What they don’t
>   know is that in some cases the **iron is actually added in the form of metallic, elemental iron**—nails for breakfast!

Like permeakra commented, only a small amount iron, whether metallic or as a compound, is safe to consume.  See [iron poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_poisoning) for details.

Comment: FeCl3 LD50 = 450 mg/kg . Iron IS harmful in large quantities.

Comment: Toxic effects begin to occur at doses above 10–20 mg/kg of elemental iron https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_poisoning

Comment: @permeakra everything is harmful in large quantities.